# how to make a electric steam vapourizer at home

Tags: resistors, power-electronics, metal

I want to make a durable electric steam vapourizer ( basically used to inhale steam to give comfort for nasal block and also facial steaming).
I have bought quite few from the market and i see it goes off within few months or max an year.
Some models i have (http://www.amazon.in/Facial-Sauna-Vaporiser-Steamer-Inhaler/dp/B00IWKKCQC)

I plan to make a durable/atleast maintainable one using the existing base(plastic) models i have. So want your help in getting the electrical & electronic components for the same.
So questions like what should be the type of heating metal( whats the best to use). what would the electrical circuit look like resistor/capacitor specification.

By the way i use AC 220V/50Hz power line. So please do suggest.

Comment: Maybe you should be analysing the reason why these things fail and working on improving that aspect. This time next year you could be a millionaire.

Comment: @Andy aka: unfortunately designing stuff that fails right about after it's out of warranty is the winning business model most of the time these days [for run-of-the-mill consumer goods].

Comment: Yeah I know!!!!

Comment: That product cost about 3 USD- pretty cheap. Does it actually use a heater or are they just sticking a couple probes into the water from the 220V?

Comment: Reason it goes off is because it is using low quality components, some catch rust and some burn off and heating metal seems to be off bad quality.

Answer (score 1):

I built a very durable steam vapouriser using a standard electric kettle, and a way of supplying it with a reduced power. This has the advantage that the vapouriser is cheap, readily available, is run well below its normal power rating so should last forever, and can be plugged in directly at first to heat the water quickly, before going to reduced power for long term steam generation.

Being an engineer, I happened to have an auto-transformer to hand. However, it is easy enough to buy fairly cheaply fixed transformers, or variable power controllers for heaters like [this](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/thyristor-power-controller-assemblies/0841930/). Don't use a conventional lighting controller triac dimmer, it won't have the current capacity, unless you use a very low power kettle like a tiny 'travel kettle'. Choosing the amount of reduced power going to the kettle gives you a choice of the rate of steam production.

If you are happy with wiring mains components yourself *and doing it safely*, then wiring a light bulb or a motor-run capacitor in series will reduce power to the kettle.